# Avatar gives me an error when i try to call it

Tags: class, processing

Processing cannot locate my class in the main method.

I tried looking for extra or missing brackets, but didn't find any.

The error reads "Cannot find a class or type named "Avatar"", and i'm not sure what the problem is. I am fairly confident that the class is set up correctly

```
class Avatar {

  int x1;  //location variables of the main body parts
  int y1;
  int x2;
  int y2;
  int x3;
  int y3;

  Avatar() {
    x1 = 300;
    y1 = 200;
    x2 = 300;
    y2 = 350;
    x3 = 300;
    y3 = 550;
  }//end of constructor

  void display() {
    //main body
    fill(255);  //white
    noStroke(); //no line on the outside
    ellipse(x1, y1, 150, 150);  //head
    ellipse(x2, y2, 200, 200);  //middle portion
    ellipse(x3, y3, 300, 300);  //bottom portion
    //additional parts

    //sunglasses
    rectMode(CENTER);  //sets all rectangles to draw from the center
    fill(0);
    rect(260, 190, 40, 25);
    rect(340, 190, 40, 25);
    ellipse(260, 200.5, 40, 19.5);
    ellipse(340, 200.5, 40, 19.5);
    stroke(0);
    line(240, 180, 350, 180);
    line(200, 155, 250, 180);
    line(400, 155, 359, 180);

    //Smile
    arc(float(300), float(211), float(65), float(75), float(0), PI);

    //Leather Jacket
    fill(0);
    ellipse(x2, y2, 200, 200);
    fill(175);
    ellipse(300, 300, 15, 15);
    ellipse(300, 350, 15, 15);
    ellipse(300, 400, 15, 15);

    //Arms
    strokeWeight(25);
    fill(0);
    line(100, 550, 205, 300);
    line(500, 550, 395, 300);
    ellipse(100, 550, 25, 25);
    ellipse(500, 550, 25, 25);

    //belt
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    fill(35);
    rect(x2, y2+90, 200, 60);
  }//end of display function
}//end of avatar class
```

the main function is just:

```
Avatar p1Avatar;
Avatar p2Avatar;
```

Comment: Runs without error on my system.  Need to add setup() and draw() if you want to see the avatar.  How did you try to call it?

Comment: Following apodidae's lead, I would look into how you instantiate this class. Heads up for your next question: make sure that we can reproduce the issue with the code you give us, it'll make it waaay easier for us and will improve your chances to get a good answer.

Comment: yeah, the problem was i didnt have anything in setup or draw. thanks for the help.